# Add a percentage column to a simple t-SQL group by query

Tags: t-sql, group-by

I have this simple query

```
select status,count(*) as [Count] from sms_deliverylog
where dt_log>'2015-03-23' and dt_log <'2015-03-24'
group by status with rollup
```

giving this result

```
status  Count
ACCEPTD 33
DELIVRD 554
EXPIRED 2
PENDING 72
REJECTD 1
UNDELIV 2
NULL    664
```

- How can I add a simple Percentage column based on count.
- How can I rename NULL above to "Total"

Thanks

**EDIT:**
Please is there a simple t-sql alternative that does not involve using a CTE

Comment: Why do you not want to use a CTE?

Comment: Looks a bit "too much" for this otherwise simple query

Comment: @Aidan will your CTE solution be simpler than the offered answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't call it simple, but here's my attempt:

```
SELECT
  status,
  count,
  ((CONVERT(DECIMAL, count)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sms_deliverylog WHERE dt_log>'2015-03-23' and dt_log <'2015-03-24'))) * 100 AS '%'
FROM
(
  SELECT
    CASE 
      WHEN status IS NULL THEN 'Total' 
      ELSE status 
    END AS [status],
    COUNT(*) AS [count]
  FROM 
    sms_deliverylog
  WHERE 
    dt_log>'2015-03-23' and dt_log <'2015-03-24'
  GROUP BY STATUS WITH ROLLUP
 ) AS statuscounts
```

Fiddler Link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5549f/8/0